# All privileges app on Android from IntelliJ

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I recently switched mobile phone operator and I brought my number with me. However, the number stored in the SIM, which is visible to Android, is incorrect (it is the number that was given to me before the switch over).

Somebody wrote a little app a few years ago that allows changing the number on the SIM:

https://github.com/fommil/MyPhoneNumber/blob/master/src/org/lytsing/myphonenumber/MyPhoneNumber.java

I have no idea how the original author ever got it to compile, I've needed to use reflection ([as others have discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369648)).

But there is an additional problem: apparently this must be run by an app signed with the "system signature key": https://stackoverflow.com/a/6029410/1041691

[There is IntelliJ documentation for signing Android apps](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/generating-a-signed-apk-using-a-wizard.html), but I am failing to interpret/translate the (Eclipse) instructions for dealing with this fabled "system" key: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3651653/1041691

**How do I run an app on my Nexus 5 with full access?** (which is physically connected by USB)

Comment: I am not very sure but I don't think they store your phone number on SIM (it is retrieved from your operator when you turn on your phone)

Comment: @KevinT yes and that is the correct number.  But there is also a number on the SIM, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I run an app on my Nexus 5 with full access?

You don't, except perhaps by compiling your own version of the Android OS from source, rolling that into a ROM mod, and installing that ROM mod. Then, the signing key will be your own generated one, and you can sign other SDK apps with that key to grant them access to `system`-level permissions.

You might be able to install some off-the-shelf ROM, if they publish their signing key, and I have no idea if any of them do. I certainly wouldn't.

Comment: have you got a link to a walkthrough for that?

Comment: @fommil: Not really. It's not exactly within StackOverflow's purview, either. The XDA forums are probably the biggest home for that sort of knowledge, besides the ROMs themselves (e.g., CyanogenMod).